# Generating a swagger schema for a generic list in c#

Tags: c#, swagger, schema, swagger-ui

Hello im using swagger in a .NET API project, and trying to generate a schema from a generic list in C#. I have a class with a property of applicants, applicants can have types of applicant, or buisness. When I make the property a type of List swagger ui is presenting value as a string. ex String

below is my class

```
public class UpdateSfsLoanStatusRequest
{ 
   [XmlArray("Applicants")] 
   [XmlArrayItem("Applicant", Type=typeof(Applicant))] 
   [XmlArrayItem("Business", Type=typeof(Business))] 
   public List<object> Applicants { get; set; } 
   public class Applicant 
   { 
   } 
   public class Business 
   { 
   } 
}
```

below is the request body swagger is generating

```
<UpdateSfsLoanStatusRequest> 
    <Applicants>string</Applicants> 
</UpdateSfsLoanStatusRequest>
```

im trying to achieve something along the lines of the below

```
<UpdateSfsLoanStatusRequest>
   <Applicants> 
      <Applicant> 
      </Applicant> 
      <Business> 
      </Business> 
   </Applicants> 
</UpdateSfsLoanStatusRequest>
```

ive tried creating custom schemafilters using the ISchemaFilter interface to no avail.

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!